# Changing Format of 2 Columns in DF in R

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

I have 12 separate CSVs both are formatted identically in Excel. however, after uploading to R 1 of them can't be merged because they are formatted wrong. How can I change those 2 columns in December to the formatting in January?

```
str(December)
started_at = col_character(),
ended_at = col_character()
 $ started_at        : chr [1:131573] "12/27/2020 12:44"                                       
 $ ended_at          : chr [1:131573] "12/27/2020 12:55"


str(January)
started_at = col_datetime(format = "")
ended_at = col_datetime(format = "")
$ started_at        : POSIXct[1:259716], format: "2020-11-01 13:36:00"
$ ended_at          : POSIXct[1:259716], format: "2020-11-01 13:45:40"
```

Comment: Can you specify the `col_types = 'c'` to read as character assuming you are reading with `read_csv` from `readr`

Comment: @akrun Yes they read as characters but I want them to read as POSIXct so I can merge the two.

Comment: I meant that while reading all the datasets, specify as `c` so that it reads as character, then you can change it easily with `anytime::anytime(c("12/27/2020 12:44",  "2020-11-01 13:36:00"))#
[1] "2020-12-27 12:44:00 EST" "2020-11-01 13:36:00 EST"`

Comment: Can you try the code below

Comment: @akrun my webpage just updated. i will try now.

Comment: You may check the solution I posted or use the solution by @ktiu by converting those datasets individually for those having an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is different in `csv`s, can read as `character` class by specifying the `col_types = 'c'` and afterwards convert to `Datetime` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

files <- list.files("/path/to/your/directory",
             full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.csv$")
lst1 <- map(files, ~ read_csv(.x, col_types = 'c') %>%
                mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), anytime)))
```

If we need as a single dataset

```
dat <- map_dfr(files, ~ read_csv(.x, col_types = 'c') %>%
                mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), anytime)), .id = 'grp')
```

Comment: Will this impact the rest of the various formats in the spreadsheet?

Comment: @AnalystAnthony In the datasets you showed, there are only two columns.  So, I specified `everything()` i.e. all columns to be converted to datetime class.  If there are other columns as well, we need tochange that `everything()` to either `c(started_at, ended_at)` or if those date column names are different, but have the same column index specify the index as `c(1,2)` - 1st and 2nd column

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input 
x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `started_at` doesn't exist.

Comment: @AnalystAnthony i already mentioned the issue.  i.e. if your datasets doesn't have those as column names, specify the column index

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to convert with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(December, across(.fns = \(x) as.POSIXct(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")))
```